# ¿ Existe alguna manera de dar un salto de linea dentro de un acumulador de texto en java?

Tags: java, joptionpane

```
package acumtextoo;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Acumtextoo {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      acumtexto();  
    }

    public static void acumtexto(){
        
       int num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,num6,num7;
       String acumTexto = "";
       
       num1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese un valor"));
       num2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese un valor"));
       num3 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese un valor"));
       num4 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese un valor"));       
       num5 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese un valor"));
       num6 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese un valor"));
       num7 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese un valor"));
       
       acumTexto = acumTexto + "EJEMPLO " + num1 + "Ejemplo" + num2 + "Ejemplo" + num3 + "Ejemplooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo " + "\n";
       
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,acumTexto);
       
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Hay alguna de dar un salto de linea donde esta el acumulador de texto?

Comment: si buscas dar salto de linea luego de Ejemplo+num podes hacer lo siguiente `acumTexto = "\nEjemplo" + num1 + "\nEjemplo" + num2 + "\nEjemplo" + num3;`

Comment: Listo muchas gracias amigo me funciono perfecto gracias por el dato :)